# Unable to reclaim free space after bootcamp uninstall

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, diskutil

I'm unable to reclaim free space after uninstalling Boot Camp (done through the Boot Camp Assistant).

Here are some screenshots from Disk Utility and results from `diskutil`:

[image: Disk utility screenshot]

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         771.3 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         228.7 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         27.7 GB    disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +799.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     365.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 1.8 GB     disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            8.9 GB     disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 8.9 GB     disk2s5s1
   
$ diskutil info disk0
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE HDD ST1000DM003

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  SATA
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000204886016 Bytes) (exactly 1953525168 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               No
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No

$ diskutil info disk1
   Device Identifier:         disk1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk1
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM0032L

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 28.0 GB (28000002048 Bytes) (exactly 54687504 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   No
   Hardware AES Support:      No

$ diskutil info disk2
   Device Identifier:         disk2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk2
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SM0032L

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Disk / Partition UUID:     A267C17A-5F6E-42B8-8B18-0F212E883B18

   Disk Size:                 4.6 EB (4611686789742047232 Bytes) (exactly 9007200761214936 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Virtual:                   Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

   This disk is an APFS Container.  APFS Information:
   APFS Physical Store:       disk1s2
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              Yes
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: raphaelmsx: I realize your computer is using APFS and your question was closed as a duplicate of a question where legacy Core Storage is being used. In other words, any answers given at the other question would be useless to you. However, your question is probably a duplicate of some other question where APFS is being used in a Fusion Drive arrangement. We do get many questions similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The Terminal application command to enter is given below.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

If this command does not work, post the output to your answer.